# ReactJS populating into multiple div's instead of li

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Writing my first ReactJS App and what I need it to do is create a couple of div's with some dummy content which I will later update with real fetches from the site.

So far this is the code I've written to accomplish this.

```
class Joke extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      jokes: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    //test content
    let jokes = ['first joke', 'second joke', 'third joke'];

    const jokes_div = jokes.map((joke) => {
        return (
            <div className="card col-md-7">
              <div className="card-body">
                 {joke}
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className="main-card-body">
            {jokes_div}
        </div>
        
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Joke />,
  document.getElementById('jokes')
);
```

On the html there's a div with an id of `jokes`, problem is once ReactJS loads it throws multiple errors till the page stops responding.

## Error Message

```
ReferenceError: errors is not defined[Learn More]  main-script.js:21:3
    window.onerror http://35.196.142.180/static/js/main-script.js:21:3
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:178:7
    ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:227:5
    commitRoot http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:16181:7
    completeRoot http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17196:34
    performWorkOnRoot http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17141:9
    performWork http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17060:7
    performSyncWork http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17032:3
    requestWork http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:16932:5
    scheduleWork$1 http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:16796:11
    scheduleRootUpdate http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17363:3
    updateContainerAtExpirationTime http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17390:10
    updateContainer http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17417:10
    ReactRoot.prototype.render http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17700:3
    legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer/< http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17840:9
    unbatchedUpdates http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17257:10
    legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17836:5
    ReactDOM.render http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-dom.development.js:17895:12
    <anonymous> http://35.196.142.180/:56:1
    n http://35.196.142.180/static/js/babel.min.js:12:27047
    r http://35.196.142.180/static/js/babel.min.js:12:27558
    o/</< http://35.196.142.180/static/js/babel.min.js:12:27873
    s/i.onreadystatechange http://35.196.142.180/static/js/babel.min.js:12:27316
```

Comment: what kind of errors are you receiving?

Comment: show your HTML file and have you import react and react component in joke class file?

Comment: Your code is working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/m3yvjr2mk8. The only thing you are missing - you didn't define key to `<div className="card col-md-7">` - but that is just warning, no other errors.

Comment: I think you forgot to define `errors` as it says. Look back at your code and check if you've left `errors` word somewhere without defining it.

Comment: Yup. Your error has nothing to do with the code in your file.

Comment: it's weird because there's two files `main-script.js` which is supposed to deal with errors and `react-script.js` which is where the code is. I haven't edited main and I used it "as is" in the ReactJS tutorial and it didn't bring a bug. Still looking for the cause of the issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there's no needs to call constructor nowadays. Here you got nice article about that
https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599

The code looks okay, but there's no 'key' property in the outer div in the list. 
You need to inlude this, because react throws an errors. This needs to be unique value like for example index of the element. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

I've prepared working example here, so you can compare It to your code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/llonl9qp3q

the core looks like this:

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const jokes = ["first", "second", "third"];
    const jokes_div = jokes.map((item, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <p>{item}</p>
      </div>
    ));
    return <div className="App">{jokes_div}</div>;
  }
}
```

You can also improve that a little bit and call it inside the return:

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const jokes = ["first", "second", "third"];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {jokes.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <p>{item}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still, It is not the reason why it threw that error. His code is perfectly fine for instance.

Comment: Yeah this looks like some build error. Have you set everything correct? In your sample there's no react imports for example. You can always set up the project using create-react-app
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: because I'm using some precompiled React I also needed to use `React.Component` instead of `Component` alone. Otherwise not sure where the bug was but this works.